# Error: java.lang.NullPointerException error for map reduce program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, stderr

i map.java class i try to send the filename by this

context.write(new Text(stringWord), new Text(fileName))

recude.java

```
 import java.io.IOException;

 import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;

 public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int sum = 0;
    MapWritable occurenceInFile = new MapWritable();
    for (Text val : values) {
        if(occurenceInFile.containsKey(val)) {
            occurenceInFile.put(val, new IntWritable(1));
        } else {
            IntWritable occurence = (IntWritable) occurenceInFile.get(val);
            occurenceInFile.put(val, new IntWritable(occurence.get() + 1));
        }
        sum += 1;
    }
    String result = key.toString() + " (";
    boolean flag = false;
    for (Writable filenameWritable : occurenceInFile.keySet()) {
        if (flag) {
            result += ", ";
        }
        String filename = ((Text) filenameWritable).toString();
        result += filename + "=" + ((IntWritable) occurenceInFile.get(filenameWritable)).toString();
        flag = true;
    }
    result += ")\nTotal occurence of \"" + key + "\": " + Integer.toString(sum);

    context.write(key, new Text(result));
}
}
```

error code this error code is show in stderr

```
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Reduce.reduce(Reduce.java:18)
at Reduce.reduce(Reduce.java:6)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:656)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:394)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:172)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:166)
```

i begin to write a wordcount program, but i still do not know how to fix this error.

Comment: Look at lines 6 and 18 in your code.  This is a word count program?  Looks a mess.  I'm certain it's possible to write something cleaner.

Comment: yes this is not whole program, but i think there is no error in my map.java and wordcount.java(Main class)

Comment: You thought wrong.  There is an error.  The JVM just made it clear.  I'm sure this could and should be written more clearly.  I'd recommend a JDK8 stream based version before trying it with Hadoop.  If you can't do that, you have little chance with the big hammer.  Do something simple first.

Comment: I like ... There is no error in my code, why is it crashing ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess line number #18 is this one:

`occurenceInFile.put(val, new IntWritable(occurence.get() + 1));`

so it is possible that `occurence` variable value, which is read on previous line, is `null`. Another variant is that `occurence.get()` value is `null`.

So, it is hard to suggest what can cause it exactly, but you should debug your program and find, why can `occurenceInFile.get(val);` return `null` value.